# Eager Loading Lambda Error in EF 6.0.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to use eager loading with EF but it throws an error  "cannot convert lambda expression"

Code :

```
var medicos = db.Medicos.Include(m => m.Cidade)
            .Include(m => m.Especialidade).ToList();
```

I saw something similar questions and a tried

```
var medicos = db.Medicos.Include(x => x.Cidades.Select(a => a.Especialidades));
```

but that doesn't work either

Any solutions? I have a `using` for `System.Linq` already.

Comment: To verify this **throws** an error at runtime?  From the looks of this code I expect a compile time error.  If compile time please give exact error.  A definition of the two Medicos properties would be helpful.

Comment: Is this using `ObjectQuery`? That `Include` doesn't have an overload that would accept a lambda expression (try `Include("Cidade")`).

Comment: NeverMind, i made a typo .... where  Include(m => m.Cidade) should be  Include(m => m.Cidades) to match table name... Shame on me :/, Thanks anyway ! ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer...

My problem here was a typo where

```
Include(m => m.Cidade)
```

should be

```
Include(m => m.Cidades)
```

to match the table name, EF didn't found table name "Cidade" and thought it was a string

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have these using

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```